# How to control dropdownlist auotpostback in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdown, ispostback

I have a dropdownlist with autopostback and an update panel, it works correctly, 
but I have also other controls in my page with autopostback.
What I need is to control when the page is  autopostback but the dropdownlist is not autopostback do something, like this:

```
     If is not Page.autopostback then
    'do something

else if is not MyDropdownlist.autopostback then    
    ' do something different    
    End if
```

I can use this:

```
If is not Page.autopostback then
End If
```

But I can´t do this:

```
If is not MyDropdownlist.autopostback then
End If
```

So how can I do this? I hope my explanation has been helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain in details what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I´m sorry I explain wrong, I want to do some code but only when the page is autopostback but the dropdownlist is not autopostback

Comment: May be you use Page.IsPostback property for page postback and check dropdown's selected value. Not sure why you required such thing. Explain clear logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__EVENTTARGET` request form variable has the name of control that caused postback to happen. You can query the name of this control and do whatever you want to do.

For example,

```
If IsPostBack Then
    Dim postBackControlId As String = Request.Form("__EVENTTARGET")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(postBackControlId) Then
        If postBackControlId = "DropdownList1" Then
            ' the postback happened due to DropdownList1

        Else
            ' the postback happened due to some other control.

        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, It´s works correctly, it was just what I was looking for :-D